Why is one boxer allowed to hit their opponent, risking serious injury?
In a boxing match, each of the contestants routinely tries to get direct hits against the other's head and body and to injure them enough to make them incapable of continuing the fight.
At the same time, they are trying to prevent getting hit, so you can't really argue that they were asking to get injured (for what that would be worth in court).
Why is a boxer who gives their opponent a concussion or worse (boxers sometimes die) not normally liable for the completely foreseeable results?
I'm from Germany, but I'm interested in how this works in the US and other places as well.
PS: This is more or less the opposite question: is an MMA fighter liable under specific circumstances.

https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=boxing https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=contact+sports
